# Fit boxes side-by-side with css and html

Tags: html, css

I have a project, where i want to display 8 article boxes, side by side. 
It should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ei6sc.png)
I currently have only the first box, when i try add the other boxes, they don't stay in the same space, as the first one is, how would I accomplish that? I want to add them side by side, like it is on the picture provided.

Answer (score -1):

im not a css expert but you might start with that:

```
<div style='width:100%'>

<div style='float:left;width:25%'>content 1</div>

<div style='float:left;width:25%'>content 2</div>

<div style='float:left;width:25%'>content 3</div>

<div style='float:left;width:25%'>content 4</div>

</div>
```

that devides your container div by 25 % - 4 times.